# There is an error message of {"cod":"400","message":"wrong latitude"} when fetching weather data

Tags: flutter, geolocation, openweathermap

My networking class does its job at fetching my longitude and latitude but whenever I use the http.get method to fetch the weather, It throws an error message, also the status code is 400

```
Networking _networking = Networking();
const apiKey = '342a6e161ec06e5aeba1482eb65a30ab';

getWeatherData() async {
  var latitude = await _networking.latitude;
  var longitude = await _networking.latitude;

  Response response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(
        'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={$latitude}&lon={$longitude}&appid=$apiKey'),
  );
  print(response.statusCode);
  print(response.body);
}
```

Below are the **errors** I get printed out to the console

```
I/flutter ( 7834): {"cod":"400","message":"wrong latitude"}
I/flutter ( 7834): 5.1315083
I/flutter ( 7834): -1.2794733
```

Comment: your both latitude and longitude are same `var latitude = await _networking.latitude;
  var longitude = await _networking.latitude;`

Comment: Hello please I corrected the longitude but its still printing the same error message

Comment: You probably should remove your APP ID from the question, it is not necessary to give you an answer and it seems like something you should keep secret

Comment: Trying the request on curl it works fine, since you are using the same value for longitude and latitude, and the longitude is not giving you an error, I imagine that the value is something between 90 and 180, or their negative equivalents, which is valid for longitude but not latitude. Can you check on the network tools to see what the request parameters are?

Comment: please where should I check that??

Answer (score 0):

```
getWeatherLocation()async{
    Location locate= Location();
    await locate.getLocation(); //add the class in which you calling  the location from without the line here you will get this error
    NetworkHelper network = NetworkHelper(url: Uri.parse(
        '$openWeatherUrl?lat=${locate.latitude}&lon=${locate.longitude}&appid=$apiKey&units=metric'),);
   var weatherData=  await network.getData();
   return weatherData;

  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Matter of fact, the code highlighting on this site (as well as your IDE) already shows you the error:

This is wrong:

```
'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={$latitude}&lon={$longitude}&appid=$apiKey'
```

This would be correct:

```
'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&appid=$apiKey'
```

The next time, instead of guessing around, just print the string/url you are trying to format after having done so and it should be obvious.